# Como puedo filtar datos de un formato json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

Hola como va una pregunta,

Tengo un pequenio problema al filtrar 2 campos de un formato json, para incluirlo al store de redux, pero al hacerlo me incluye todo el json al store de redux (el arbol de redux me coloca demasiado dato que no voy a usar)

Yo solamente necesito extraer los campo country_name y country, para luego envarlo al dispacth de redux

El formato es https://ipapi.co/json/

Arbol de Redux:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

My code

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formato Json:

```
{
"ip": "*",
"city": "Bogotá",
"region": "Bogota D.C.",
"region_code": "DC",
"country": "CO",
"country_code": "CO",
"country_code_iso3": "COL",
"country_capital": "Bogota",
"country_tld": ".co",
"country_name": "Colombia",
"continent_code": "SA",
"in_eu": false,
"postal": "111311",
"latitude": 4.6493,
"longitude": -74.0617,
"timezone": "America/Bogota",
"utc_offset": "-0500",
"country_calling_code": "+57",
"currency": "COP",
"currency_name": "Peso",
"languages": "es-CO",
"country_area": 1138910.0,
"country_population": 47790000.0,
"asn": "AS10620",
"org": "Telmex Colombia S.A."
```

}

Comment: ¿Nos mostrarías por favor lo que has intentado?

Comment: Esto, loque tengo: ```export const UserData = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOADER,
  });
  try {
    const results = await axios.get('https://ipapi.co/json/');
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DATA,
      payload: results.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR,
      payload: error.message,
    });
  }
}; ``` todo me funciona correctamente pero lo que estoy inteando es solamente extraer 2 campos de la consulta, por que en si la consulta me trae mucho datos que no voy a usar

Comment: He tambien intentado const { data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate } } = await axios.get(url); return { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo es un objeto y quieres dos de sus propiedades puedes hacer esto:

```
const prueb = {

    country_name : results.data.country_name,
    country: results.data.country

}
```

Comment: Fue lo primero que hice pero me colocaba  undefined

Comment: luego haces `payload : prueb`? porque si  haces `prueb.data` es undefined

Comment: Si claro, const results = await axios.get('https://ipapi.co/json/');
    const prueb = {
      country_name: results.country_name,
      city: results.city,
      david: 'Hola'
    };

    dispatch({
      type: USER_DATA,
      payload: prueb,
    }); Haciendo las pruebas solo me manda al store a david, pero country_name and city, me lo coloca como nulos. Fotos https://prnt.sc/s2trw0

Comment: Revisé la respuesta de axios y los datos están en una propiedad llamada `data`, ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verda lleve toda la manina intentando hacerlo, cuando termine mi proyecto sera los primero en verlos :)

Answer (score 1):

Puede no ser la mejor opción pero yo lo haría así:

- Itero en 2 variables para obtener solo aquellos valores cuya clave coincida con el deseado
- Cuando estemos filtrando indicamos entre corchetes el nombre de la clave que deseamos recuperar
- Esas variables las pasamos a una estructura de objeto al momento de imprimirla

```js
    let data = [
      {
        "ip": "*",
        "city": "Bogotá",
        "region": "Bogota D.C.",
        "region_code": "DC",
        "country": "CO",
        "country_code": "CO",
        "country_code_iso3": "COL",
        "country_capital": "Bogota",
        "country_tld": ".co",
        "country_name": "Colombia",
        "continent_code": "SA",
        "in_eu": false,
        "postal": "111311",
        "latitude": 4.6493,
        "longitude": -74.0617,
        "timezone": "America/Bogota",
        "utc_offset": "-0500",
        "country_calling_code": "+57",
        "currency": "COP",
        "currency_name": "Peso",
        "languages": "es-CO",
        "country_area": 1138910.0,
        "country_population": 47790000.0,
        "asn": "AS10620",
        "org": "Telmex Colombia S.A."
      }
    ]
    
    
    let country_name = data.map((elemento) => elemento = elemento["country_name"])
    let country = data.map((elemento) => elemento = elemento["country"])
    console.log({ country_name, country })
```

Con una salida así:

```
[object Object] {
  country: ["CO"],
  country_name: ["Colombia"]
}
```